# Embedding sub-footer with Ryan Fait's method

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a sub-footer on top of my footer, [like so](http://i.imgur.com/Dd1xRgq.jpg)

- header+footer(blue)
- sub-footer(red)

I used Ryan's sticky-footer method, so my HTML looks like this

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class='logo'>Logo</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="root-footer"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id='subfooter'>
            <div class='subfooter-content'>
                <a id="main-nav01" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_self">トップ</a>
                <a id="main-nav02" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_self">「世界のKitchenから」の思い</a>
                <a id="main-nav03" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_self">タイのお母さんのKitchenから</a>
                <a id="main-nav04" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_self">ちいさなKitchenのムービー</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and my CSS for the subfooter like this

```
#subfooter
    position: relative


    .subfooter-content
        position: absolute
        margin-top: -200px
        height: 70px
        z-index: 10
```

but it doesn't work on FF, if you see the [screen-shots](http://i.imgur.com/aSu2C39.jpg) (FF is on the right), the subfooter(red) follows the footer(blue)

**edit**

I used compass and in the actual design it uses outline top, which i'm having problem with in FF.

here's the jsbin http://jsbin.com/fifeleru/1

Comment: could you please include the rest of the CSS code, it is necessary to answer the question and also format it as proper CSS (adding `{}` and `;`)

Comment: ah, forgot to mention, 

I used compass and in the actual design it uses outline top, which i'm having problem with in FF.

here's the jsbin http://jsbin.com/fifeleru/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `outline:1px solid blue` by `border-top:1px solid blue;` on the `.footer` the problem is solved.

[See here](http://jsbin.com/fifeleru/2/edit)

Comment: I tried that, it adds 1px to the footer, which made the scrollbar appears

Comment: @badcoder OK, you can use `box-sizing:border-box;` on `.footer` to correct that.

Comment: @badcoder oh yes, sorry, that property needs the `-moz` prefix like this : `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` see here : http://jsbin.com/fifeleru/6/edit